# Magit is unbearably slow on WSL2

Tags: magit

I'm running magit in a medium-small project, on WSL2 through xming on windows 10.

The startup time for magit is in the high tens of seconds, and so is every other action.
This is *not* the case in the repository for my emacs config which is also much smaller, so I wonder if I did something to the repo to make it so slow..

On the other hand, running git directly from the WSL2 terminal works great.

This is the CPU profiling from emacs (not sure how this would render here...):

Would love any advice, Thanks!

> - command-execute                                                                              9460  98%
> - call-interactively                                                                          9460  98%
> - funcall-interactively                                                                      9428  97%
> - magit-status                                                                              9425  97%
>   - magit-status-setup-buffer                                                                9425  97%
>
>   - magit-setup-buffer-internal                                                             9425  97%
>   - magit-refresh-buffer                                                                   9418  97%
>   - apply                                                                                 9418  97%
>   - magit-status-refresh-buffer                                                          9417  97%
>     - magit-run-section-hook                                                              7558  78%
>
>     - apply                                                                              7558  78%
>
>     - magit-insert-unstaged-changes                                                     2845  29%
>     - magit-insert-untracked-files                                                      2509  26%
>     - magit-insert-status-headers                                                        971  10%
>     - magit-insert-unpushed-to-upstream-or-recent                                        510   5%
>     - magit-insert-stashes                                                               374   3%
>     - magit-insert-staged-changes                                                        193   2%
>     - magit-insert-unpulled-from-upstream                                                123   1%
>     - magit-insert-merge-log                                                              25   0%
>     - magit-insert-sequencer-sequence                                                      3   0%
>     - magit-insert-rebase-sequence                                                         2   0%
>     - magit-insert-am-sequence                                                             1   0%
>     - magit-insert-bisect-rest                                                             1   0%
>     - magit-insert-bisect-log                                                              1   0%
>       + magit-git-exit-code                                                                 1859  19%
>
>   - magit-status-mode                                                                         6   0%
>   - magit-get-mode-buffer                                                                     1   0%    + execute-extended-command
>     2   0%    + doom/toggle-profiler
>     1   0%   + byte-code
>     32   0%
>
> - ...                                                                                           160   1%
> - redisplay_internal (C function)                                                                 4   0%
> - evil--jump-hook                                                                                 2   0%   winner-save-old-configurations
>   1   0%

Comment: Is your larger repository stored within the Linux filesystem inside WSL2 or on a Windows drive? Accessing the Windows filesystem from WSL 2 is known to be quite slow. I regularly access a rather large repo located inside the WSL2 filesystem, which is nearly as fast as under Linux directly.